# How to make the program work when calling a function instead of using a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is the code of an [NBack test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-back#/media/File:Single_n-back_task_animation.gif).
When I execute the code as it is, it works. The sequence that appears on the screen is

```
self.sequence = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,6,6,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1])
```

But I have a function that generates sequences that I want to use instead of that array. It is ZBack.py
When I call my ZBack.py `self.sequence = generateZBackSequence(20, 5)` instead of the array, the program does not work. 
It outputs this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Python_Scripts/N-back.py", line 198, in targetTask
for i in range(self.sequence.shape[0]):
AttributeError: 'NBack' object has no attribute 'sequence'
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why does it tell me the attribute 'sequence' does not exist?
I have already checked indentation. My ZBack.py does return an array too.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread
from keylogger.KeyLogger import KeyLogger
from time import sleep
from nBackTools.NBackTools import *
from nBackTools.ZBack import *

from random import randint
import numpy as np

import csv


def _create_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
    return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
tk.Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle


class NBack:

    def __init__(self, master):

        ##Title of the window
        self.master = master
        master.title("N-Back")

        ##It measures the screen size (width x height + x + y)
        ##The opened window will be based on the screen size
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}-0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=master.winfo_screenwidth(), height=master.winfo_screenheight(), \
                            borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="grey")


        self.canvasWidth = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.canvasHeight =  master.winfo_screenheight()

        self.createLines()
        self.createText()

        self.canvas.grid()


        self.t = Thread(target=self.targetTask,)
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()


        ## Positions of the circles ("stims")

        ##          -   -                      
        ##        0 - 1 - 2                     
        ##      ------------                   
        ##       3  - 4 - 5                      
        ##      ------------                   
        ##       6  - 7 - 8                      
        ##          -   -                        

        self.positions = np.array([[(self.canvasWidth/2)-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)-130],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2), (self.canvasHeight/2)-130],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2)+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)-130],\
                              [(self.canvasWidth/2)-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2), (self.canvasHeight/2)],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2)+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)],\
                              [(self.canvasWidth/2)-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)+130], \
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2), (self.canvasHeight/2)+130], \
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2)+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)+130]])


        ###############################################
        ###############################################
        #THIS IS THE PROBLEM!!!

        #self.sequence = generateZBackSequence(20, 5)
        self.sequence = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,6,6,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1])

        ###############################################
        ###############################################

"""

ADDING LINES TO THE SCREEN

"""


    def createLines(self, linewidth = 5):
        #Vertical 1
        self.canvas.create_line((self.canvasWidth/2)-65, (self.canvasHeight/2)-65-130, \
                            (self.canvasWidth/2)-65, (self.canvasHeight/2)+65+130, width= linewidth )
        #Vertical 2
        self.canvas.create_line((self.canvasWidth/2)+65, (self.canvasHeight/2)-65-130, \
                            (self.canvasWidth/2)+65, (self.canvasHeight/2)+65+130, width= linewidth )
        #Horizontal1
        self.canvas.create_line((self.canvasWidth/2)-65-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)-65, \
                            (self.canvasWidth/2)+65+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)-65, width= linewidth )
        #Horizontal2
        self.canvas.create_line((self.canvasWidth/2)-65-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)+65, \
                            (self.canvasWidth/2)+65+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)+65, width= linewidth )


"""

ADDING TEXT TO THE SCREEN

"""


    def createText(self):
        self.canvas.create_text((self.canvasWidth/4), (self.canvasHeight - self.canvasHeight/4), text="A=YES", font=( None, 20))
        self.canvas.create_text((self.canvasWidth/4), (self.canvasHeight - self.canvasHeight/4)+50, text="S=NO", font=( None, 20))



"""

CIRCLES APPEAR AND DISAPPEAR

"""


    def targetTask(self):
        thisnb = randint(75,900*2)

        targetFile = open(str(thisnb)+"_targets.csv",'w', newline='')
        writer = csv.writer(targetFile)

        ##Loops from 0 to the Number of circles that will appear (default=20)
        for i in range(self.sequence.shape[0]):
            posX = self.positions[self.sequence[i]][0]
            posY = self.positions[self.sequence[i]][1]

            print(": (%d,%d)" % (posX,posY))
            ##Records the coordenates in an excel file
            writer.writerow([posX,posY])

            ## How many seconds each circle will appear
            circle = self.canvas.create_circle(posX, posY, 55, fill="black", outline="#000", width=1)
            sleep(1)

            ## Delete circle
            ## How many seconds circle dissapears
            self.canvas.delete(circle)
            sleep(2)


        sleep(1)
        print('All done')
        targetFile.close()
        self.master.destroy()

root = Tk()
my_gui = NBack(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the ZBack.py:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def generateZBackSequence(nbTrial, nbOfYes):
    ##all possible positions of the "stims"
    allStims = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    ##sequence is an array of -1s and has the size of nbTrial (default=20)
    sequence = np.zeros((nbTrial,))-1

    ##security: in case the required "yeses" are too many
    if nbOfYes > nbTrial:
        print('generateZBackSequence: invalid nb of Yeses')
        return None

    ##Pick randomly 1 stim and repeat it (default=5)
    yeses = np.repeat(random.sample(allStims, 1),nbOfYes)
    print("yeses:", yeses, '\n')

    ##Making the first value in the sequence = value in yeses
    sequence[0]=yeses[0]
    #print("sequence:", sequence, '\n')

    ##Contains the "stims" that were not randomly sampled
    newStims = [x for x in allStims if x not in yeses]
    #print("newStims:", newStims, '\n')


    """

    STEP 1 - impose the yeses

    """


    ##nbOfYes-1, because there is already a "yeses" in sequence[0]
    for i in range(nbOfYes-1):
        idxValid = False

        while idxValid==False:
            ##select index randomly, from 1 to 19
            idx = random.randint(1, nbTrial-1)

            if sequence[idx]==-1:
                idxValid = True
        print("idx:", idx, '\n')

        ##insert yeses in the random index
        sequence[idx] = yeses[i]
        #print("sequence_idx:", sequence)


    """

    STEP 2 - fill in the sequence

    """


    ##Makes a "for" from 0 to 19
    for i in range(sequence.shape[0]):
        if sequence[i]==-1:
            stimValid = False

            ##Search for -1s
            while stimValid==False:
                ##Takes a random sample "stim" which is different from 'yeses'
                stimID = random.sample(newStims, 1)
                ##stimID is a list of 1 element, sequence is an array of 20 elements
                sequence[i]=stimID[0]
                stimValid = True

            else:
                stimValid = True


    return sequence


def _test():
    print(generateZBackSequence(20,5))
    print("")
    print(np.arange(0,20,1))
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are calling the method `targetTask()` within `NBack`'s constructor, in the lines below

```
self.t = Thread(target=self.targetTask,)
self.t.daemon = True
self.t.start()
```

before it has the chance to define the `sequence` attribute.

It would be fixed by defining `sequence` and anything else you need before you call `targetTask()`.

The constructor would look like this:

```
    def __init__(self, master):

        ##Title of the window
        self.master = master
        master.title("N-Back")

        ##It measures the screen size (width x height + x + y)
        ##The opened window will be based on the screen size
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}-0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=master.winfo_screenwidth(), height=master.winfo_screenheight(), \
                            borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="grey")


        self.canvasWidth = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.canvasHeight =  master.winfo_screenheight()

        self.createLines()
        self.createText()

        self.canvas.grid()

        # Notice we define self.sequence before calling self.targetTask
        self.sequence = generateZBackSequence(20, 5)


        ## Positions of the circles ("stims")

        ##          -   -                      
        ##        0 - 1 - 2                     
        ##      ------------                   
        ##       3  - 4 - 5                      
        ##      ------------                   
        ##       6  - 7 - 8                      
        ##          -   -                        

        self.positions = np.array([[(self.canvasWidth/2)-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)-130],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2), (self.canvasHeight/2)-130],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2)+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)-130],\
                              [(self.canvasWidth/2)-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2), (self.canvasHeight/2)],\
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2)+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)],\
                              [(self.canvasWidth/2)-130, (self.canvasHeight/2)+130], \
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2), (self.canvasHeight/2)+130], \
                               [(self.canvasWidth/2)+130, (self.canvasHeight/2)+130]])


        self.t = Thread(target=self.targetTask,)
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()
```

Comment: It worked, although I started having another problem: 'IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices' So I made modifications in ZBack which was returning float64 instead of int32

Comment: Glad to have helped.